# Point of tangency is an optimal point for a monotone, quasi-concave function

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Given $U : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotone and quasi-concave, consider the following problem :
>
> $$\max_{(x,y) \ \in \ \mathbb{R}^2}[U(x,y)] \text{ subject to } p_1 x + p_2 y \leq M ; \ (p_1, p_2 > 0)$$
>
> **1. If a level curve of $U$ is tangent to $p_1 x + p_2 y = M$ at some point $(a,b)$ on such that the slope of the tangent is $-\frac{p_1}{p_2}$, then show that it is an optimal point.**

> I have seen the tangency condition to be written as $\displaystyle \frac{df(x)}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial y}} = -\frac{p_1}{p_2}$ where $f: (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ describes the level curve around the point $(a,b)$.
>
> **2. Is it possible to have $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = -\frac{p_1}{p_2}$ but one or both of $\frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial U(x,y)}{\partial y}$ are not defined?**

---

**My attempt:**

If $U$ is differentiable at all points, then the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_condition) is satisfied and **(1)** follows. For **(2)**, each term is defined due to our assumption.

The problem lies when $U$ is not differentiable everywhere. In that case, how do we show that the point of tangency is an optimal point? I don't know if the tangency condition requires all the derivatives in **(2)** to be defined in the interval around $(a,b)$; assume differentiability of $U$ in that particular region around $(a,b)$ only if that is a necessity.

---

**Definitions:**

1. Quasi-concavity of $U$ :

   - (Definition $1$) If $U(r) \geq U(s)$ for $r,s \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $U(\lambda r + (1-\lambda)s) \geq U(s) \ \forall \lambda \in [0,1]$.
   - (Definition $2$) The set $S_\alpha := \{ (x,y) : U(x,y) \geq \alpha\}$ is convex for all values of $\alpha$.
2. Monotonicity of $U$ :

   - $r \geq s \implies U(r) \geq U(s)$ where $r \geq s$ means $(r_1 \geq r_2) \land (s_1 \geq s_2)$ for $r = (r_1, r_2)$ and $s = (s_1, s_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

For your question 2: there can be a function with discontinuities, which still has smooth level curves.

E.g. $U(x, y) = x + y + \lfloor x+y \rfloor$. It is monotone, quasi-concave, and level curves are straight lines; but the function is discontinuous at lines where $x + y$ is an integer.

For question 1: instead of "tangent", it seems the following lighter condition may work: if a level curve of $U$ has an intersection with $p_1 x + p_2 y = M$, and the level curve is entirely on one side of $p_1 x + p_2 y = M$. That would free us from differentiability. But I have no proof of it.

Comment: Two quick follow-ups: **(i)** The level curve of $x+y+\lfloor x+y \rfloor = 2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $x+y=k$. Is that correct? I mean to say that the individual level curves do not have a point of discontinuity. **(ii)** Again, just to clarify, this example does not contradict our original problem, right? No level curve forms a tangent unless $p_1 = p_2$. When $p_1 = p_2$, we have $\frac{df(x)}{dx} = -1 = -\frac{p_1}{p_2}$ and every point on it intersecting with $p_1 x+ p_2 y = M$ will be optimal. (The partials don't have not exist, so this works!) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I would have given you a +1 for the example, but it seems I need at 15 reputation points to do so.

Comment: That's right, the example does not contradict the original problem. It is there to answer positively to question 2, i.e. it shows that the level curve can be defined and have a tangent, while $U$ is not continuous (and so lacks some partial derivative).